# Rewriting URLs in WordPress not working for this scenario

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have been trying to  rewrite this specific rule in wordpress, it seems really simple but i can't get it to work.

```
Current url: topic/?topic_id=155&title=life-balance
```

AND

```
Desired url: topic/155/life-balance
```

i have very little knowledge of url rewriting, infect this is my first time rewriting urls. this is what i have tried

in ***functions.php*** file

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_seourl_rules' );
function add_seourl_rules() { 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "topic/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?",
        "topic/?topic_id=$matches[1]&title=$matches[2]",
        "top");
}
```

After adding this function, i re-saved permalinks to *flush the urls*, but its still not working.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong here.
thanks

## **EDIT 1:**

OK, i have made these changes but still not working.

```
*Step 1:*
```

My permalink was set to %%postname%% in the WP permalinks. i changed them back to normal (?p=123).

```
***Step 2:***
```

As of now, my normal pages and posts are back to plain urls.

```
normal pages: example.com/?page_id=717

normal posts: example.com/?p=2470

custom post: example.com/?page_id=717&topic_id=155&title=life-balance


***`Step 3`***
```

to rewrite my custom post url, i have changed my function to this.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_seourl_rules' );
function add_seourl_rules() { 
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^topics/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?page_id=717&topic_id=$matches[1]&title=$matches[2]',
        'top');
}
```

still can't make it work for custom post, and not sure what should i do for my normal pages and posts.

Comment: and what is your wp rewrite rule in permalink section?

Comment: it is set to post name.

Comment: You have your rules now like wrong way.. the first rule should match your current url (topic/?topic_id=155&title=life-balance) and then rewrite to desired (topic/155/life-balance) check.. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Ok i understand what you meant, but what if i want all other pages and post to show in a way like wp postname permalink, and want to write only for this kind of url for my custom posts? for example, my postname permalink shows a page url like this ( www.example.com/pagename), but for this custom post i want my urls to be ( www.example.com/155/postname)?

Comment: you really should but something else than numbers after www.example.com/. Use some entry point like www.example.com/custom/155/postname and make rule to check that "custom" word..

Comment: Can you give me an example please. in previous comment, i meant my custom posts will be like (www.example.com/topic/155/postname). 155 here is the post ID.

Comment: @Hardy i have made changes according to your suggestions, but still cant make it work. please check my Question edits.